# Macbook Air 2013 with Mac TB2 Ethernet adapter seeing slower speeds than wifi? 22.04 Kubuntu

Tags: drivers, ethernet, apple, thunderbolt, macbook-air

I have noticed when I connect to my home network via wifi.. I can hit speeds upwards of 13 MiB/s ... easily..

BUT when I plugin and use a Apple Ethernet -> TB2 adapter... I cannot hit more than 11 MiB/s ..

I didn't care for a while but now that my apartment got new gigabit internet.. I am starting to wonder if the dongle supports its full potential?

Comment: What are the specifications of the adapter? If anything like this https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC704LL/A/apple-usb-ethernet-adapter then it's 10/100BASE-T therefore it doesn't support Gigabit anyway and your results are adequate and expected for the device.

Comment: TB2 stands for Thunderbolt2 .. so the specification is as follows https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD463LL/A/thunderbolt-to-gigabit-ethernet-adapter

Comment: Interestingly yours ISN'T mentioned in the compatibility list. The only Macbook Air in the list says "11-inch, Early 2015" and this Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)#Thunderbolt_2 also suggests Macbook Air only got TB2 in early 2015. I think the mystery is solved and, as expected, nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I solved the issue.. infact the TB2 interface works perfectly fine.. the culprit was some wall socket Ethernet connections.. so the issue is not as you say with Ubuntu nor the Ethernet -> TB2 adapter.. when I plug straight into the router I get Gigabit speeds thankfully.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was the wall ethernet wiring.. NOT the OS nor the adapter.. when I plugged straight into the router all works fine.